# jersey 2.2: ContainerResponseFilter and ContainerRequestFilter never get executed

Tags: java, rest, jersey, grizzly

Following the getting started guide on the Jersey website:

I executed the following build command:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
-DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.2
```

I then followed the tutorial on

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e6783

to add a custom ContainerResponseFilter:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
static @interface CORSBinding {}

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR)
@CORSBinding
static class CrossDomainFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext creq, ContainerResponseContext cres) {
        Logger.getLogger("com.example").log( Level.INFO, "before: {0}", cres.getHeaders());
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
        Logger.getLogger("com.example").log( Level.INFO, "after: {0}", cres.getHeaders());
    }
}

@Provider
static class MyResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("MyResponseFilter.postFilter() enter");
        responseContext.setEntity(
                responseContext.getEntity() + ":" + getClass().getSimpleName(), null, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
        System.out.println("MyResponseFilter.postFilter() exit");
    }
}

...
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@CORSBinding
public String helloWorld() {
    return "hello world";
}
```

I tried to register this filter with Named Binding and with Dynamic Binding, nothing works.

To easily reproduce, I also tried an example from the official resources:

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.2/examples/exception-mapping

The same problem: the custom filters do not get executed.

Is this a Grizzly problem?

Comment: How does your resource class look like? Is your resource method annotated with @CorsBinding as well?

Comment: Yes, I added the missing code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out you have to manually register the custom classes - as in:

```
rc.register(com.dummy.mypackage.CORSResponseFilter.class);
```

Full example:

```
/**
 * Main class.
 *
 */
public class Main {
    // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://192.168.1.34:8080/myapp/";

    /**
     * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
     * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
     */
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and in com.example package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.dummy.mypackage");

        //NEW: register custom ResponseFilter
        rc.register(com.dummy.mypackage.CORSResponseFilter.class);

        // Register Jackson JSON
        rc.packages("org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jackson").register(JacksonFeature.class);

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding the following code in **web.xml** using Tomcat container is what worked for me:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>my.package.SecurityRequestFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>`
```

My thanks goes to:

http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/