# javascript fetch cors error with java server

Tags: javascript, java, rest, reactjs

I have a java server handling RESTful services on port 8080 using Glassfish/Jersey libraries (I do not have a web.xml file as I am hosting the services in the console app).   I am running a webpack-dev-server with ReactJS on port 8081.   In my ReactJS control I make a GET request from my RESTful service.  When I make that call I get the following error:

```
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/realtime/initialize. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This is the javascript code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/realtime/initialize', {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            mode: 'cors',
        } 
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log("financial services initialization ok");
        this.setState({loginState: 1});
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("financial services initialization error: " + err);
        alert("initialized failed");
    });
```

here is my java class:

```
package Application.Server;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import Application.Server.Contracts.GeneralResult;

@Path("/realtime")
public class RealTimeServices {
    private int count = 1;

    @GET
    @Path("/initialize")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public GeneralResult initializeAccount() {
        outputService.showMessage("connecting attempt: " + count);          
        count ++;           
        return new GeneralResult("request made");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is--I under cors is a browser security issue but don't understand what it means to handle cors.  My attempt to fix it fails.

I've tried adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to the javascript http call but that still throws an error and I do not get the results back.

It seems like I need change something in the java code, but Im happy if there is something I can change in the javascript.

Thank you 
Matt

Comment: You need to enable CORS from your web service.

Comment: @TimothyKanski do you know how to do that?

Comment: I'm not a java dev but perhaps this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: @TimothyKanski.  thnx.  I understand.  I am not using spring io.  I am using grizzly in console app.  Apparently I chose an unusual route for hosting my RESTful services.

Comment: What about this?  http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/

Comment: Thank you.  That was close.  It lead me to this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842390/jersey-2-2-containerresponsefilter-and-containerrequestfilter-never-get-execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the cors issue by adding a response filter to the grizzly server instance.  I started with the filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.google.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Provider
public class ServerResponses implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");       

    }

}
```

Then I added that class during the server start up code like this:

```
public HttpServer startServer() {
    final WebServerResourceConfig rc = new WebServerResourceConfig();

    rc.register(Application.Server.ServerResponses.class);

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(configurationService.RootWebServiceURI()), rc);
}
```

My answer is based on this [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842390/jersey-2-2-containerresponsefilter-and-containerrequestfilter-never-get-execute) post.  As @rook pointed out, this may be an insecure solution.  It works for me as I will not be deploying my server.

Thank you
Matt

Answer (score 0):

This web service requires a request handler for the [OPTIONS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS). The standards try and make it hard to disable critical security features like the same-origin policy (SOP), so that you have to be very intentional on what features you expose.

In this particular API call, it doesn't look like a response is required.  I'm not sure why you would want to undermine the SOP.

Comment: I intentionally left out all of the logic so to keep the code as concise as possible.  Please assume I need to fix cors/SOP problem.

Comment: @tatmanblue then please assume you need an `OPTIONS` pre-flight request handler.  I know for a **absolute fact** that if you don't need to read the response, then you don't need CORS.  This is the point of cross-site request forgery (CSRF) and I exploit this on a regular basis. SOP is never a problem, unless it is keeping you from writing an exploit.